# How can I catch the ng-model value into sortable options [ui-sortable]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have this
html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">   
  <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="item.levels">
       <li  ng-repeat="level in item.levels" >
          <ul>
            <li>{{level.title}}</li>
           </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul> 
</div>
```

I want to catch the ng-model value into sortableOption to make order changes in database
the sortableOption would be the following into controller:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
  update: function (e, ui) {
    console.log('How can I catch the ng-model value?');
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('[ui-sortable="sortableOptions"]').attr('ng-model')
```